# external distributed memcache not workking

Tags: memcached, nextcloud

this is my first post on here.
I installed the latest version of Nextcloud (19.0.0) on one machine and try to split all the services to different vm's. that means DB (mariadb), Storage, redis (for file locking), memcached (distributed cache) on different machines, all of which are running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This setup is a bit janky, but it helps me better understand, how each service functions. The DB-Server and Redis are working fine. Now I want to get memcached to work. as soon as i add the parameters i get an internal server error. this is what I have in my config.php

```
  array (
    0 => '10.10.10.45',
    1 => 'nextcloudtest.test.lan',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/nextcloud-data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '19.0.0.12',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://nextcloudtest.test.lan',
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => '10.10.10.49',
  'dbport' => '3306',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbpassword' => 'password',
  'installed' => true,
 // 'memcache.local' => '\OC\Memcache\APCu',

'memcache.distributed' => '\\OC\Memcache\\Memcached',
'memcached_servers' => array(
     array('10.10.10.47', 11211),
),
  'memcache.locking' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\Redis',
  'filelocking.enabled' => 'true',
  'redis' => 
   array (
  'host' => '10.10.10.46',
  'port' =>6379,
  'timeout' => 0.0,
   ),

);
```

Then i get this error in the nextcloud.log

```
\\OC\\Memcache\\Memcached not available for distributed cache","Code":0
```

I did set the bind address in the memcached.conf to 0.0.0.0 so it accepts all incoming connections and also added a rule to the firewall to allow incoming connections on port 11211.

I hope you guys cane give me some tipps.